# Prove directly from the definition that a given set S is not sequentially compact in the reals.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Let $S=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\ N\}$. Prove directly from the definition that $\ S$ is not sequentially compact in $\ R$.

From the definition that my professor gave, for any sequence in $\{x_n\}$ in $\ S$, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that converges to a limit ${x \in\ S}$.

In order to prove the statement above, can't I just prove that limit of $\ S$ is $0$, but $0$ is not in $\ S$, therefore it is not sequentially compact?

Answer (score 4):

No, because $S$ is a set. What is the limit of a set?

Take the obvious sequence: $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. It does't converge in $S$, right? Therefore, $S$ is not sequentially compact.

Comment: To the proposer: In other words,be careful with your terminology, especially if marks are at stake.